# Converting Data.Time.UTCTime to / from ByteString

Tags: haskell, bytestring

Let's say I need to do write/read of a `Data.Time.UTCTime` in "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" format many many times to/from a file.

It seems to me that, using `Data.Time.formatTime` or `Data.Time.parseTime` to convert `UTCTime` to/from `String` and then packing/unpacking the `String` to/from `ByteString`, would be too slow since it involves an intermediate `String`. But writing a `ByteString` builder/parser of `UTCTime` by hand seems like repeating a lot of work already done in `formatTime` and `parseTime`.

I guess my question is: Is there a systematic way to get functions of type `t -> String` or `String -> t` converted to `t -> ByteString` or `ByteString -> t` with increased efficiency without repeating a lot of work?

I am totally a Haskell newbie, so please forgive me if the question is just stupid.

Comment: This is not a stupid question.

Answer (score 5):

No, there isn't a general way to convert a function of type `t -> String` to one of type `t -> ByteString`. It might help you reconcile yourself to that reality if you recall that a ByteString isn't just a faster `String`; it's lower-level than that. A `ByteString` is a sequence of bytes; it doesn't mean anything more unless you have an encoding in mind.

So your options are:

1. Use function composition, as in phg's answer:

   ```
   import Data.ByteString.Char8 as B

   timeToByteStr :: UTCTime -> ByteString
   timeToByteStr = B.pack . formatTime'

   parseBStrTime :: ByteString -> Maybe UTCTime
   parseBStrTime = parseTime' . B.unpack
   ```

   where I've corrected the function names. I've also used, e.g., parseTime' instead of parseTime, to elide over the format string and `TimeLocale` you need to pass in.

   (It's also worth noting that `Data.Text` is often a better choice than `Data.ByteString.Char8`. The latter only works properly if your `Char`s fall in Unicode code points 0-255.)
2. If performance is an issue and this conversion profiles out as a bottleneck, write a parser/builder.
3. Just use `String`s.

The last option is an underrated choice for Haskell newbies, IMHO. `String` is suboptimal, performance-wise, but it's not spawn-of-the-Devil. If you're just getting started with Haskell, why not keep your life as simple as possible, until and unless your code becomes too slow?

Comment: In other words, the `Char8` functions is equivalent to [ISO-8859-1 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-1).

Answer (score -3):

If you're not really in the need of heavily optimized code, the usual and easiest way is to use function composition:

```
timeToByte = toBytes . formatTime
byteToTime = parseTime . fromBytes
```

or something like that, as I'm not familiar with those libraries.

If after profiling you recognize that this approach is still to slow, I guess you will have to write something by hand.

Comment: Why wouldn't you worry about efficiency? What if @shih is having to do a million of these conversions as fast as possible?